# How to throw exception collectively

Tags: java, validation, exception, production-environment

Let's say we have a list of some ID's on which we need to perform some check and if check fails we are throwing an exception. This is pretty trivial what I want to do is check the whole list and throw an exception with ID which fails a check and with a proper message.
How should I approach this problem? Any production level advice.
Example:
I am calling an API 'X' which gives a response as 'Y' if no exception is thrown. I am passing a list of ID's to 'X' Api.

Request Body

```
List<Employee> employeeIds = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I am making a check in the backend for each Id. Lets say Id 1,3,5 fails the validation So I want to throw an exception with message that ID 1,3,5 failed because of 'abc' reason.

What I am currently doing is throwing an exception as soon as we fail the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply collect errors from all id checks and then report them. You can create your own exception:

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    private List<Long> ids;

    public void addId(Long id) {
        if (ids == null) {
            ids = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        ids.add(id);
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return ids != null;
    }
}
```

and example usage:

```
Collection<Long> employeeIds = null; // your input
final MyException exception = new MyException();
employeeIds.forEach(id -> {
    // surround with try-catch if there's no other way
    try {
        // do your checks for a given id
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // if any error received
        exception.addId(id);
    }
});

// later on..
if (exception.isError()) {
    throw exception;
}
```